# How to exclude the ES Meven dependencies jars，when “maven install” an ES plugin

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, plugins, maven-dependency-plugin

I wrote an ES plugin in eclipse，and execute "maven install" to built a .zip package。

Then go to ES 'bin' directory, install this plugin, report error as:

> ERROR: java.lang.IllegalStateException: jar hell!
>   class: com.spatial4j.core.context.jts.DatelineRule
>   jar1: /opt/srv/elasticsearch-2.3.4/lib/spatial4j-0.5.jar
>   jar2: /tmp/4666854054181704172/temp_name1369332854/spatial4j-0.5.jar

It turn out to be the ES Meven dependencies jars included in this plugin .zip package, such as spatial4j-0.5.jar, compress-lzf-1.0.2.jar, elasticsearch-2.3.4.jar, lucene-suggest-5.5.0.jar etc.

These jars will collide with the ES's dependent jars in ES 'lib' directory.

How can i exclude these 'Meven dependencies' jars? I tried to modify pom.xml and 'src/main/assemblies/plugin.xml', but failed.

Answer (score 0):

In the `<dependency>` tag of your colliding jars, you need to put the `<scope>` to **provided**. This way they won't be included in the final build on the package phase, but they will be included for local compilation